# Object Manager access

Tags: object, guest-user, system-admin, object-manager

How can I give access to Object manager to a particular user having the profile which not having access to object manager.? Any Alternate way other than assigning System Admin Profile , Also I dont want to change Profile..urgent please

Comment: you can use [permission sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/perm_sets_overview.htm) :)

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi And which permission do we need?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at "Delegated Administration": https://help.salesforce.com/htviewsolution?id=000004559

Here you can specify which custom objects the user should be allowed to manage.

There is also the permission "View Setup and Configuration" permission which can be assigned via a permission set. This will enable them to access (view only) the setup menu without having to give them the System Admin profile.

Comment: And what about standard objects?