# How to give access to Object Manager via permissions without making the user an administrator?

Tags: permissions, system-permissions

I'm looking for a way to give a specific user the ability to make changes to Lead and Opportunity via the "Object Manager" screen without giving them access to full admin permissions.

I've seen [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337603/object-manager-access), but the answer there suggests delegated administration, and the options for that only control editing *custom objects* so that doesn't seem to be what I require. Someone in the comments on that question suggested some permission in the normal permissions system but I can't find one. Note that even if delegated administration gave access to edit all standard objects by default, this is not what I want.

What is the solution for this? Is there one?

Comment: AFAIK there is no specific system or app permission to give access to the "Object Manager" screen just for select objects. I believe `Customize application` permission gives the access to the users for managing fields, layouts etc. from the "Object Manager" screen for all/ most objects. (1) Do you want this user to view/ manage only the "Object Manager" screen for Lead & Oppty and nothing else in the setup pages? (2) Have you listed down what actions the user can perform on Lead & Oppty?

Comment: @arut Basically the requirement is that the user can add additional fields to these objects independent of the development team.

Comment: `without giving them access to full admin permissions.` >> (1) If there is no concern with user being able to view the admin pages and manage fields/ layouts on all objects, then simply clone the system admin or standard user profile & revoke all the access that would let him/ her edit the admin settings. You can do this simply via another profile or delegated admin. (2) On the other hand, if you have concerns, then there isn't an OOB functionality AFAIK. You could create a custom component, expose it to this user and use metadata API underneath for creation of fields in Leads and Oppty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a new profile based on a clone of an existing Admin profile and then strip away all permissions for that profile.

Another option is to create a Flow that performs what changes this user needs to be able to do on their behalf using the Admin profile.

Counter-intuitively, given the broad capabilities the Admin profile has, the latter is probably the easier.

Comment: I guess there really isn't a better option. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't even aware you could use Flows to change object metadata like that.